# What is the need of creating a new user for tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I am new at Linux(Ubuntu) and I was searching for a guide to install and configure Apache Tomcat on Ubuntu Linux. By following [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-5-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial I successfully managed to install and configure Tomcat. In the Step 3 of that tutorial, it is mentioned that it will install tomcat under the user tomcat and change the owner of the tomcat directory to the tomcat user, and make all files in the bin directory executable. So, the question that I want to ask is that what is the need of creating a new user for tomcat ?
Thanks.

Comment: Privilege separation, so that tomcat getting hacked doesn't mean your entire server is owned.

Comment: @muru This is only for security measure.

Comment: Do I also need to create a new user for mysql ?? @muru

Comment: If you install MySQL from the repositories, it already creates a separate `mysql` user

Comment: Does this also applicable on tomcat. Means If I install tomcat from repositories, it will create a separate tomcat users. @muru

Comment: Yes, the `tomcat7` and `tomcat6` packages do create users (called `tomcat7` and `tomcat6` respectively).

Comment: Thanks @muru for your help. And what about tomcat9 ?

Comment: No idea, never tried it.